# Firechat how to fetch the most recent 10/20 messages in a chat room

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using firechat, and would like to fetch the most recent 10 messages from firebase, i know you can fetch all the messages in a chat room, and only display 10 in the front end, but i was wondering if there's any advanced query to only get 10 most recent messages from a particular room? I am using the default firechat data structure, every "room-messages" will have bunch of messages under it that's belonging to that chat room. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an optional `options` parameter into [the `FirechatUI` constructor](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/src/js/firechat-ui.js#L17):

```
function FirechatUI(firebaseRef, el, options) {
```

Which is then passed down to Firechat, where it's [used to limit the number of messagges](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/src/js/firechat.js#L349):

```
self._messageRef.child(roomId).limitToLast(self._options.numMaxMessages).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
```

So this should work:

```
var chat = new FirechatUI(chatRef, 
                          document.getElementById('firechat-wrapper'), 
                          { numMaxMessages: 10 });
```